# Directly get data.table from SQL Server R

Tags: sql, r, database, import

I usually import databases into R by combining the `DBI` and `odbc` packages:

```
connection <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
data <- dbGetQuery(connection, SQL_statement)
```

The method `dbGetQuery()` returns my variable `data` as a `data.frame`. Is there a method on directly getting a `data.table` employing a similar way?

Comment: `dbGetQuery(connection, SQL_statement) %>% setDT()`  ?

Comment: Thanks denis, but then I will load and store it as a data.frame which I then transform into a data.table.

Comment: There is no tool that queries the data and bypasses the `data.frame` step to `data.table`. The cost of the intermediate `data.frame` step is near-zero, since everything that makes a `data.table` a `data.table` has to be done regardless of whether it's coming from an existing `data.frame` or somehow from a db-fed stream. What is your concern?

Comment: Marcus, are you able to quantify problems or slow-downs you're experiencing by retrieving into a `data.frame` and converting with `as.data.table` or `setDT`? Perhaps what you're seeing as a problem can more accurately be attributed to something else in the process.

Comment: Thanks, I was simply wondering if there is an option. If not, it is completely fine!

Comment: If it is possible to convert to a `data.table` on the server side to then reduce fecthing time to the local R session? Or does the notion of a `data.table` only exist in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As r2evans said, there is no such method.